# parse libcurl response with nlohmann json or rapidjson

Tags: c++, json, libcurl, rapidjson, nlohmann-json

My libcurl code returns me a json string:

```
{"object":"user","attributes":{"id":000,"admin":false,"username":"un","email":"google@gmail.com","first_name":"leopold95","last_name":"leopold95","language":"en"}}
```

I want parse this string in my objects (my problem isn't in it).
But when I try parsing this with nlohmann or rapid I am getting an error.
But if I try parse this string:

```
string str = "{\"object\":\"user\",\"attributes\":{\"id\":36,\"admin\":false,\"username\":\"a4qsmr9m\",\"email\":\"leopold9586@gmail.com\",\"first_name\":\"leopold95\",\"last_name\":\"leopold95\",\"language\":\"en\"}}";
```

with nlohmann everything works fine. With rapid I do not get any errors either.

So, my question is:

**How can I parse the first string with nlohmann ?**

or

**How could I replace all *"* with *\"* in my response?**

*And, of course `replace(s, "", "");` `replace(s, '', '');` , `replace(s.begin(), s.end(), ""/'', ""/'');`
don't work for me. In some situations I have my "replaced symbols" at the end of the string*

If needed I can add more code or publish the project to git

EDIT:

```
UserInfo Engine::testIU(string link)
{
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;

    string readBuffer;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    struct curl_slist* headers = NULL; //headers struct
    if (curl) {
        //headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Authorization: Bearer imr8VuU9L6qUTjyZQ0srCNyfFE7Ru0v8VOLZBMd8bhjxJFfP");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers); //add headers
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, link.c_str());   //set url
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); //set http method

        //curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTR, true);

        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, &readBuffer); /* data goes here */

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        curl_slist_free_all(headers);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    json j = json::parse(readBuffer);

    testUserI.id = j["attributes"]["id"].get<int>();
    testUserI.admin = j["attributes"]["admin"].get<bool>();
    testUserI.username = j["attributes"]["username"].get<string>();
    testUserI.email = j["attributes"]["email"].get<string>();


    return testUserI;
}


struct UserInfo
{
    int id = 0;
    bool admin = NULL;
    string username = "";
    string email = "";
    string first_name = "";
    string last_name = "";
};
```

- 

```
{"object":"user","attributes":{"id":0,"admin":false,"username":"a4qsmr9m","email":"google@gmail.com","first_name":"leopold95","last_name":"leopold95","language":"en"}}
```

***EDIT 2: so if you have the same problem just fix this in your code:***

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
```

***and see answer above and all comments there***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `json.exception.parse_error` you get is due to the fact that `"id":000` not valid JSON. It should most likely be `"id":0`.

The proper way to fix this is to ask the other end to correct the mistake.

> How could I replace all `"` to `\"` in my respose?

That wouldn't help and would in fact make the JSON even more invalid. The `\` in your initialization of `str` does not become a part of the string and the only reason why you think that works is because the `id` field, `"id":36`, in that string *is* valid. Replace it with `"id":000` and you will see that it will fail to parse that too.

A note on the added `curl` code. The below isn't correct and will cause undefined behavior:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, &readBuffer);
```

The argument to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` should be a `char*`, not a `std::string*`. Remove that option if you're not using it for posting.

You need to supply the `std::string*` via `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` and cast it back to a `std::string&` in your `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` callback.

Example:

```
size_t WriteCallback(char* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userdata) {
    std::string& buf = *static_cast<std::string*>(userdata);
    buf.append(ptr, std::next(ptr, nmemb * size));
    return nmemb * size;
}

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
```

---

For testing you don't have to escape all the `"` with backslashes, just use a raw string literal.

Example: (change `"id":000` to `"id":0` and it'll work)

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using json = nlohmann::json;

int main() {
    std::string str =
        R"aw({"object":"user","attributes":{"id":000,"admin":false,"username":"un","email":"google@gmail.com","first_name":"leopold95","last_name":"leopold95","language":"en"}})aw";
    try {
        auto j = json::parse(str);
        std::cout << j.dump(2) << '\n';
    } catch(const json::exception& ex) {
        std::cerr << "Parse error: " << ex.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:
`Parse error: [json.exception.parse_error.101] parse error at line 1, column 38: syntax error while parsing object - unexpected number literal; expected '}'`

Output with the error fixed:

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "admin": false,
    "email": "google@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "leopold95",
    "id": 0,
    "language": "en",
    "last_name": "leopold95",
    "username": "un"
  },
  "object": "user"
}
```

---

With the input in your edited question:

```
std::string str =
    R"aw({"object":"user","attributes":{"id":36,"admin":false,"username":"a4qsmr9m","email":"leopold9586@gmail.com","first_name":"leopold95","last_name":"leopold95","language":"en"}})aw";
```

It would be successfully parsed and the program above would print:

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "admin": false,
    "email": "leopold9586@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "leopold95",
    "id": 36,
    "language": "en",
    "last_name": "leopold95",
    "username": "a4qsmr9m"
  },
  "object": "user"
}
```

Comment: a added some more example code. can u told me what i do wrong?

Comment: @Leopold95 Yes and I see that you've added the `curl` part to the question too - but that part is **not** the problem so you can remove that from the question. The problem is that the sender (the URL in `link`) is not sending valid JSON. You are not doing anything wrong that I can see. The error should be fixed on the server side. Do you know who's responsible for the server side? Is it within your company?

Comment: @Leopold95 I also noticed something odd in your `curl` code. Is that really the code you used to get the string as you showed it in your question? It doesn't look like it should work for that.

Comment: curl sends me first string in my question and id = 0 or id ='some number'. i have parse error but i cant understand why. if i copy thouse string into "string  = "{}"; " and add '\' to every ' " ' for str format - everything works fine. I cant undestand why, because this is the same strings. do u have any ideas?

Comment: @Leopold95 ... but, I explained why. It doesn't matter if you add a `\ ` for every `"`. It will _still_ fail to parse `"id":000` because it's not valid JSON. Have you asked the people behind the service that you are `curl`ing why they send an invalid `id` when the `id` is `0`?

Comment: curl cant send me id:00 or id:0000000, only id:0 - i was changed it in first json

Comment: @Leopold95 Look in your own question. It says `"id":000`. Did you fix the bug in your `curl` code that I mentioned in the answer?

Comment: see my question - here is latest json answer

Comment: @Leopold95 See my edited answer. Have you tried my program with the JSON strings you've given as examples? Did you fix the `curl` bug I mentioned?

Comment: yes, with your string everything works fine.

Comment: Copy my string into your program and compare it, `char` by `char`, with the string you get from `curl` to see if there's a difference. I've asked three times now, but, did you fix the `curl` bug I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: yes, now i added your curl code. so, if i use your string and comment my curl code evry works fine. if i use ypur string and not comment curl code - i have erre in line where i call this method. if i use curl responce i have new error " Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FF9471FFD01 (ntdll.dll) в cpp.exe: 0xC0000005 "

Comment: wuld u like i publish my project on git?

Comment: @Leopold95 It's better if you only take the necessary pieces from that project and create a [mre] that you put in the question here. Otherwise it won't be of much use for other people coming here looking for an answer to a similar question later.

Comment: wait a mont ill piblish it. ill answer my problem if i remove problem

Comment: is it possiblr for u not to texting in comments? any other social networks? telegram, instagram, viber, discord, skype

Comment: https://github.com/Leopold95/ForStackOverFlow here is link on git. files u need its Engine.h/.cpp and cpp.cpp

Comment: @Leopold95 Questions asked here should be answered here. The purpose of Stackoverflow is to provide a Q&A so that other people with similar problems can find answers here. I see that your code still contains the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` bug I mentioned though. It should be `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: hahahhaha im in shock now every works fine... omg....

Comment: @Leopold95 There you go :-D

Comment: ok, but what should i use for put, post, delete ?  CURLOPT_WRITEDATA or CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS if curl sends me json strings

Comment: `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` is for the `void*` you get in the `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` callback. I usually create a C++ object and pass `this` to `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` so that you get a pointer to the whole object in the callback. I've actually not used `curl` for [`POST`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html) operations yet but I'm guessing it's just to put the data you want to `POST` in the field exactly as you want the server to receive it.

Comment: ok, im very very very gratefull u!!! if i have some more problems with post, , , etc can i ask u? )

Comment: @Leopold95 Glad it helped! You're welcome! If you have more questions, just post them here on Stackoverflow. If I see it, I may have an answer. There are however many many people here that may be able to answer. If you want your question to get more attention, try to make a small example program that we can copy and compile _as-is_ that shows the problem you ask about. People will usually be a lot more keen on answering if they get a [mre].